# matplotilb: update only axis using existing data

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt5

I'm developing a desktop application with PyQt and using matplotlib to plot data (list of 32 floats). Data is coming from embedded device continuously with certain time intervals and whenever new data is coming, then application is notified and it automatically (via connect) plots the data to canvas. This works as expected.

Now I would like to implement unit selections for Y and X axis. I use radio select buttons for that, there is five options for Y axis and two for X axis. When user changes unit selection for either of axes, existing data should be replotted with new unit selection. One more thing is that zoom level should be kept when updating.

This is my current plotting function (keeps the zoom level):

```
def plot(self, spectrum: list):
    spectrum = self.calculate_spectrum_values(spectrum)
    self.line.set_data(self.x_dimension, spectrum)
    self.canvas.draw()
```

Unit selection for X axis is only affecting to which units to show (pixels or wavelength) and it's linear so it doesn't affect to shape of the data. Unit selection for Y axis is affecting what happens in calculate_spectrum_values() method, I do different mathematics for data with different selections. I have another methods which changes the unit selection. For X axis it's like following:

```
def set_xaxis(self):
    if self.unit_selection_x == "Pixels":
        self.axes.set_xlabel('pixel')
        self.x_dimension = numpy.linspace(1, 32, 32)
    elif self.unit_selection_x == "Wavelengths":
        self.axes.set_xlabel('wavelength')
        self.x_dimension = numpy.linspace(400, 700, 32)
    else:
        raise ValueError
    self.axes.set_xlim(self.x_dimension.min(), self.x_dimension.max())
```

This current implementation works okay when measurement is running since new data comes around one second intervals, so within that time new data is always updated with new unit selection. But I would like this to work so that unit selection is independent of data update and it should also work when measurement is not running. In that case it should replot the existing data when unit selection is changed. How to do that?

Other problem is how to keep zoom level when unit selection is changed. Currently it always goes to default state, but I would like to implement this so that if user is zoomed in/out, this same zoom position is shown after unit selection is changed. Any idea how I could preserve the zoom state and update axes at the same time?

So in short, how I can update only axis in matplotlib and not to touch to zoom or data but use existing values instead?

Comment: After reading this, I have problems understanding the actual problem. What is the question? What exactly would answer need to contain to solve your problem?

Comment: Sorry, I agree it was very bad explanation. I did some edits, hopefully it's easier to understand now.

Answer (score 0):

First you would need to introduce a way to convert from the one unit to the other. In this case, there is a linear relationship between the two, which makes it very easy.

```
#calculate wavelength, given pixels
p2w = lambda x: (700.-400.)/(32.-1.)*(x-1.)+400.
# calculate pixels, given wavelength
w2p = lambda x: (32.-1.)/(700.-400.)*(x-400.)+1.
```

You can then get the current axis limits, and apply the according transformation from above. For converting from pixels to wavelength,

```
xmin, xmax = ax.get_xlim()
ax.set_xlim(p2w(xmin), p2w(xmax))
```

or for converting from wavelength to pixels

```
xmin, xmax = ax.get_xlim()
ax.set_xlim(w2p(xmin), w2p(xmax))
```

You can do the same with the data

```
xdata = self.line.get_xdata()
self.line.set_xdata(p2w(xdata))
```